# array_walk not working as expected when modifying the values

Tags: php

I am trying to add a new value to the array (I know it is possible with `array_map()` but I would like to test it with the `array_walk()`).

This is the code:

```php
$array = [
    [
        'id'   => 1,
        'name' => 'Jesus',
    ],
    [
        'id'   => 2,
        'name' => 'David',
    ],
];
```

And I want this output:

```php
$array = [
    [
        'id'     => 1,
        'name'   => 'Jesus',
        'locked' => 0,
    ],
    [
        'id'     => 2,
        'name'   => 'David',
        'locked' => 0,
    ],
];
```

I tried with the following code:

```php
array_walk($array, static function(array $item): array {
    $item += ['locked' => 0];
    //var_dump($item); // Here the array has the three values.
    return $item;
});

// Also I tried the same code but not returning the array, I mean:

array_walk($array, static function(array $item): void {
    $item += ['locked' => 0];
    //var_dump($item); // Here the array has the three values.
});
```

Is it possible what I want with an `array_walk()`?

---

That would be the solution with an `array_map()`.

```php
$arrayMapped = array_map(static function(array $item): array {
    return $item += ['locked' => 0];
}, $array);

var_dump($arrayMapped);
```

Cheers!

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`array_walk()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)? It explains in the first screen how to achieve what you want.

Comment: `+=` is for numbers. Read about [creating/modifying array elements with square bracket syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying)

Comment: @axiac Arrays can be added with the [`+` operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) too…

Comment: @axiac Take a look https://stitcher.io/blog/array-merge-vs+ :)

Comment: I did not say it cannot be done with `+=`. It is more natural to use `[]=`.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @axiac. To add items via key-value to an array, I recommend you using the standard way: `array[key]=value`. Or without a defined key `list[]=value`.

Comment: @axiac Ok, thanks. I will take note of that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are passed by value. You need to define the argument by reference using `&`

```php
array_walk($array, function(array &$item): void {
    $item['locked'] = 0;
});
```